# x2go with multiple remote monitors

Tags: arch-linux, remote-desktop, x2go

I'm trying out [x2go](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X2Go) on Arch Linux (local and remote) with a Cinnamon desktop environment to get remote access to the local session of my server over SSH.

My problem is that the local server has 2 physical monitors, and x2go is giving me a single double-wide window rather than 2 windows or allowing me to choose which monitor I want to forward. Is there any way to split this up either into 2 windows, or just get 1 of the two windows per session?

Comment: Did the documentation provided any value? http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:usage:multi-display

Answer (score 1):

In the x2go Session Preferences you should be seeing a Display option to 
"Use whole display" and the ability to choose which single display to broadcast.

[image]